# How do I access individual nodes in the dependency tree and constituency tree returned by the Stanford Parser?

Tags: c#, stanford-nlp, text-parsing

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using java.io;
using edu.stanford.nlp.process;
using edu.stanford.nlp.ling;
using edu.stanford.nlp.trees;
using edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser;
using Console = System.Console;

namespace Parser
{   

    class Parser
    {
        //loads the lexical parser
        private static LexicalizedParser LoadLexicalizedParser()
        {
            // Path to models extracted from `stanford-parser-3.5.2-models.jar`
            var jarRoot = @"E:\Project\stanford-parser-full-2015-04-20\stanford-parser-3.5.2-models";
            var modelsDirectory = jarRoot + @"\edu\stanford\nlp\models";

            // Loading english PCFG parser from file
            var lp = LexicalizedParser.loadModel(modelsDirectory + @"\lexparser\englishPCFG.ser.gz");

            return lp;
        }

        //gets the lexical tree for a 'sentence'
        private static Tree GetLexicalTree(LexicalizedParser lp, string sentence)
        {
            string[] words = sentence.Split(' ');   
            // This sample shows parsing a list of correctly tokenized words            
            var rawWords = Sentence.toCoreLabelList(words);
            var tree = lp.apply(rawWords);

            return tree;
        }

        //gets the constituency tree from the lexical 'tree' as a string
        private static string GetConstituencyTree(Tree tree)
        {
            return tree.pennString();
        }

        //gets the dependency tree from the lexical 'tree' as a string
        private static string GetDependencyTree(Tree tree)
        {
            // Extract dependencies from lexical tree
            var tlp = new PennTreebankLanguagePack();
            var gsf = tlp.grammaticalStructureFactory();
            var gs = gsf.newGrammaticalStructure(tree);
            var tdl = gs.typedDependenciesCCprocessed();

            string dependencyTree = String.Empty;

            for (int i = 0; i < tdl.size(); ++i)
                dependencyTree += tdl.get(i) + "\n";

            return dependencyTree;
        }


        static void Main()
        {
            var lp = LoadLexicalizedParser();
            string sentence = "This is an easy sentence.";

            Tree tree = GetLexicalTree(lp, sentence);

            string constituencyTree = GetConstituencyTree(tree);
            string dependencyTree = GetDependencyTree(tree);

            Console.WriteLine("Constituency Tree\n" + constituencyTree);
            Console.WriteLine("Dependency Tree\n" + dependencyTree);

            //// Extract collapsed dependencies from parsed tree
            //var tp = new TreePrint("penn,typedDependenciesCollapsed");
            //tp.printTree(tree);
        }
    }
}
```

In this code, I am getting the constituency tree and dependency tree as strings.
But I want to use them using the 'Tree' type itself, ie. I want to access and manipulate the nodes of the variable 'tree'. Is there any way I can do that?
Or do I have to create my own tree data structure and get the individual nodes by processing the strings('constituencyTree' & 'dependencyTree')?

[I need this for a small project that I am doing currently.]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there exist plenty of data structures to work with constituency trees and dependency trees. For constituency trees, you want to work with the [`Tree`](http://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/edu/stanford/nlp/trees/Tree.html) data structure which has many useful built-in functions to traverse trees, get all the terminal nodes, etc.

For dependency trees you can either work with a list of [`TypedDependency`](http://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/edu/stanford/nlp/trees/TypedDependency.html) objects where each `TypedDependency` represents the relation between a governor word and a dependent word, or you can work with a [`SemanticGraph`](http://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/edu/stanford/nlp/semgraph/SemanticGraph.html). To convert the list of `TypedDependency` which you named `tdl` in your example to a `SemanticGraph`, just pass the list to the constructor:

```
SemanticGraph sg = new SemanticGraph(tdl);
```

Comment: You mean, tdl right?
Anyway, thank you!
Can you give me some hints on how to traverse the tree using the in-built methods..... there are a few methods like getChild() but getChild requires the index of the child... how can i know that beforehand?

Comment: Yes, for `getChild` you have to know the index, but you can just loop through all the children (you can get all the children with `children()` or `getChildrenAsList()`).

Comment: Ok. Thanks! Also, while using the semantic graph, I get edges(dependencies) which are not there when I print the dependencies. [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/npp9jthq788bmc1/example.png?dl=0)         In the image, the first part shows the dependencies printed by the stanford parser, the second part shows the dependencies printed by me, you'll notice a few extra edges... @SebastianSchuster